# string interpolation in angular 2 /4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

how to use a variable **multicolors** defined in typescript file in our *template* ?: -

I have tried  like this `-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, {{multicolors}} 50%, lightgray 50%)` but not working , any solution?

Comment: Can you add more code? Where do you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create pipe like:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeStyle' })
export class SafeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
  }
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
<div [style.background]="'-webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, ' + multicolors + ' 50%, lightgray 50%)' | safeStyle">
  Test
</div>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDLf682NUBXS3OhC2vK9?p=preview)**

See also

- [Angular 2 - Sanitizing transfrom on SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628468/angular-2-sanitizing-transfrom-on-svg)